# How to split pages where it necessary when converting data to pdf using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation

I have dynamic data and need to split pages somewhere. Now I'm using "html-pdf" module and don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO please read some FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting because you can't ask us to write your full code.